# How to add a 10.x.x.x device to my 192.168.x.x WRT54G router?

Tags: router, wrt54g

I have a Linksys WRT54G router, currently set up with 192.168.x.x  addresses.

Now I have been loaned a device which is programmed to use a 10.x.x.x address. How can I access it? I am not allowed to change its IP address, so it looks liek I either get teh router to support two ranges, or change my home LAN to 10.x.x.x

When I look at the Linksys setup page, I see that I can change the " Local IP Address", which I guess is the router itself. There is a setting for "Starting IP  Address", but that has 192.168.1 hardcodedd & I can only change the final component.

Can anyone help me? (and is this the correct Stack Exchange site to ask this question?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linksys routers start offering IP addresses at .100 so what I would recommend (assuming the device does NOT need internet access), set your computer's IP address statically.

Use the following IP information (it should be fine unless you've set something else statically)
IP: 192.168.1.99
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1

THEN, ADD an IP address (might be an advanced tab or button, don't remember off hand).
For the added IP use the following:
IP: 10.x.x.x+1 (where you're adding 1 to the last value of x)
Subnet Mask: 255.0.0.0 (this assumes the device uses the default Class A network subnet mask)
and *IF* there's a section for default gateway, leave it blank (the only default gateway you want set anywhere on the PC is the 192.168.1.1 address).

Again, going from memory on all this, so the exact wording/interface may differ a little from my description.

Comment: +1 thanks. ok, I'll go hunt round to see where I cna add the 10.x.x.x address. Thanks

Comment: I can't see how to add a 10.x.x.x address tot eh WRT54G when it has a 192.168.1.x address  :-(

Comment: I didn't say add it to the router - I said add it to the COMPUTER.

Answer (score 1):

Change your local IP address so the first 3 numbers match your loaned device, and the last one is a 1.  Once that is changed, the first 3 numbers of the starting IP address will automatically change.  These are the addresses that get handed out to the other devices on your LAN.  You should set it so that it won't conflict with your router or your loaned device.

Comment: "Change your local IP address" - do you mean the router's address? With the WRT54G, if I do that then the "Starting IP  Address" is still 192.168.1.1

Comment: Even after a reload/refresh/apply/whatever?

Comment: +1 (and =1 for your original answer).  Ok, i'll try again & reset teh router after changing its IP address